# Adding multiple rss feeds to a script in SCALA InfoChannel Designer 5

Tags: scala-designer

Okay, since it is impossible to talk to anyone on the phone or get support through Scala's "forum", I am going to take a shot and see if anyone out there is feeling my pain.

I have a client that uses Scala's InfoChannel Designer and Content Manager. I have had to learn this software from scratch and I have to say it hasn't been easy. I think I am at a point where the overall design is set, but I need to implement a couple of things before I can make this happen.

RSS feeds are my issue at this point. Multiple RSS feeds to be specific. I need a feed coming in for 3 areas of content: Wiki News (or equivalent), local weather and a stock ticker. I have learned how to setup a "crawl" using a script example available from Scala's file center and copying and pasting into my design. But from what I have learned first hand and through reading through other forums, you can not have a feed from 3 different sources or urls happening simultaneously. Doesn't seem like it would be an issue, but apparently it is.

This small step has held up this project for far too long and I need to get it figured out. This doesn't even touch on my issue of feeding in streaming video as a background but I have gone over this in another question but with no luck thus far.

If there is ANYONE out there who is in anything similar using this software, your feedback and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks you for allowing me to vent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this through VBScript and load in the seperate urls and read the RSS in an the set the three crawls to the feed you should be able to have as many crawls as you like it just means the VBScript will be quite large.

Answer (score 0):

I am still using Scala InfoChannel 3 but one of my workarounds may come in handy for you depending on how you want to employ a given rss feed. To skip the need for Scala to do the grabbing, I downloaded Website-Watcher. This monitors the feeds and then has an Action set to export the regularly updated feeds to a text file on my network. From there I am just handling the much easier task of setting up a Text File Variable on the page.